# .NET Core 3.1 API to Accept Complex XML Object

Tags: c#, xml, api, asp.net-core-3.1, datacontractserializer

---

EDIT

XML Input would look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Object1>
   <field1>Hello</field1>
   <field2>
      <field3>World</field3>
      <field4>
         <field5>Test</field5>
         <field6>Test2</field6>
      </field4>
   </field2>
</Object1>
```

---

I am a bit stuck on how to get my API to accept a complex XML object

For example, I have a class that is like this

```
public class Object1
{
 public string field1 {get; set;}
 public Object2 field2 {get; set;}
}

public class Object2
{
 public string field3 {get; set;}
 public Object3 field4 {get; set;}
}

public class Object3
{
 public string field5 {get; set;}
 public string field6 {get; set;}
}
```

In my startup.cs file, I added this

```
services.AddControllers().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()
               .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

I then got the error that it could not deserialize the input.

So I added these Attributes to the object

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
[XmlRoot]
public class Object1
{
 [DataMember(Name = "field1")]
 public string field1 {get; set;}
 [DataMember(Name = "field2")]
 public Object2 field2 {get; set;}
}

[DataContract(Name = "field2", IsReference = true)]
public class Object2
{
 [DataMember(Name = "field3")]
 public string field3 {get; set;}
 [DataMember(Name = "field4")]
 public Object3 field4 {get; set;}
}

[DataContract(Name = "field3", IsReference = true)]
public class Object3
{
 [DataMember(Name = "field5")]
 public string field5 {get; set;}
 [DataMember(Name = "field6")]
 public string field6 {get; set;}
}
```

So now when I send the XML object over, it is now able to be somewhat worked on. I can get the field1 value and it looks like the field2 object is no longer null, but everything inside of it is null.

I am not sure how to approach this properly. Anything I am missing?

My Controller looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/xml")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateObject([FromBody]Object1 object1)
{
  var testObject1 = object1.field1; // this value is not null because it is a string datatype and not like the one below which is slightly more complex
  var testObject2 = object1.field2; //this is not null but the properties inside the object are null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set the [`DataContractAttribute.Namespace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.namespace?view=net-5.0) for `Object2` and `Object3` as well:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "field2", IsReference = true)]
public class Object2
{
 [DataMember(Name = "field3")]
 public string field3 {get; set;}
 [DataMember(Name = "field4")]
 public Object3 field4 {get; set;}
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "field3", IsReference = true)]
public class Object3
{
 [DataMember(Name = "field5")]
 public string field5 {get; set;}
 [DataMember(Name = "field6")]
 public string field6 {get; set;}
}
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eFNzrP).

Notes:

- With the [data contract serializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer?view=net-5.0), if you do not explicitly specify a namespace for a data contract object, a default is assigned as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-names#data-contract-namespaces):

  > By default, data contracts for a particular type are assigned a namespace that comes from the common language runtime (CLR) namespace of that type.
  >
  > By default, any given CLR namespace (in the format Clr.Namespace) is mapped to the namespace `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Clr.Namespace`.
- The default namespace logic of `DataContractSerializer` differs from [`XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=net-5.0).  Objects are not assigned to a namespace by default by `XmlSerializer`, so your original model works as-is with that serializer.  Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nk9KN0).

  If you would prefer to use `XmlSerializer` instead of `DataContractSerializer` I believe you could remove `AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters()` leaving only `AddXmlSerializerFormatters()`.
- An easy way to debug problems with *deserialization* is to *serialize* your model and compare the actual results with content you are trying to deserialize.  If I attempt to serialize an instance of your current `Object1` model, I get:

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
  <Object1 xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <field1>Hello</field1>
    <field2 xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
      <d2p1:field3>World</d2p1:field3>
      <d2p1:field4 z:Id="i2">
        <d2p1:field5>Test</d2p1:field5>
        <d2p1:field6>Test2</d2p1:field6>
      </d2p1:field4>
    </field2>
  </Object1>
  ```

  From which it can be seen that the namespace `d2p1:` for the elements of `Object2` and `Object3` is wrong.  (The precise namespace chosen, here `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/`, will depend on the CLR namespace of your model, which is not shown in your question.)

  Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i1A8tz).
- Your XML elements do not have `z:Id="xxx"` or `z:ref="xxx"` attributes, so I don't see any need to enable the [`IsReference` reference tracking mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/interoperable-object-references).

Comment: Thank you for that input! I did not know that I needed to also put in the namespace for all the other objects as well! Thank you so much for that clarification!